# SQL Server CE 4.0 Select records in order by sort column

Tags: sql, sql-server-ce

I've been trying to get this working for a while now, so time to ask. I'm using SQL Server CE 4.0 and the SQL statement below returns the records but I'm trying to add one more requirement to it.

In the `ShowSongRef` table, there is the `SongOrder` column. I only want to return the show where the songs are in order.

In other words, for the SongID's hardcoded below, they need to have a `SongOrder` of 1 and 2 or 4 and 5, any combination as long as it's in order, one song played right after the other and it could be a group of songs (more than two).

```
SELECT sh.ID 
FROM Songs s
INNER JOIN ShowSongRef ref ON ref.SongID = s.ID 
INNER JOIN Shows sh ON sh.ID = ref.ShowID 
WHERE ref.SongID IN ('654', '321') 

--ORDER BY sh.ID,  ref.SongOrder
```

All that would be needed is sh.ID so I've been trying a GROUP BY with no luck.
Any input is appreciated.

Thanks!

EDIT:

Here's some SQL to actually run and test

The Select suggested below is not working.

```
DECLARE @Shows TABLE (ID INT)
INSERT INTO @Shows (ID) VALUES (1)
INSERT INTO @Shows (ID) VALUES (1546)

DECLARE @Songs TABLE (ID INT, Name VARCHAR(256))
INSERT INTO @Songs (ID, Name) VALUES (1, 'Song 1')
INSERT INTO @Songs (ID, Name) VALUES (2, 'Song 2')
INSERT INTO @Songs (ID, Name) VALUES (3, 'Song 3')
INSERT INTO @Songs (ID, Name) VALUES (654, 'Song 4')
INSERT INTO @Songs (ID, Name) VALUES (321, 'Song 5')


DECLARE @ShowSongRef TABLE (ID INT, ShowID INT, SongID INT, SongOrder INT)
INSERT INTO @ShowSongRef (ID, ShowID, SongID, SongOrder) VALUES (1, 1, 1, 1)
INSERT INTO @ShowSongRef (ID, ShowID, SongID, SongOrder) VALUES (2, 1, 2, 2)
INSERT INTO @ShowSongRef (ID, ShowID, SongID, SongOrder) VALUES (3, 1, 321, 3)
INSERT INTO @ShowSongRef (ID, ShowID, SongID, SongOrder) VALUES (4, 1, 3, 4)

INSERT INTO @ShowSongRef (ID, ShowID, SongID, SongOrder) VALUES (5, 1546, 3, 1)
INSERT INTO @ShowSongRef (ID, ShowID, SongID, SongOrder) VALUES (6, 1546, 1, 2)
INSERT INTO @ShowSongRef (ID, ShowID, SongID, SongOrder) VALUES (7, 1546, 654, 3)
INSERT INTO @ShowSongRef (ID, ShowID, SongID, SongOrder) VALUES (8, 1546, 321, 4)    

SELECT sh.ID 
FROM @Songs s 
INNER JOIN @ShowSongRef ref ON ref.SongID = s.ID 
INNER JOIN @ShowSongRef ref2 ON ref2.SongID = s.ID 
                             AND Ref2.SongOrder = Ref.SongOrder + 1 
                             AND ref.ShowID = ref2.ShowID 
INNER JOIN @Shows sh ON sh.ID = ref.ShowID 
WHERE ref.SongID IN ('654', '321')
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a 2nd join to ShowSongRef to guarantee there's a 2nd song after the first in the desired order.

So the below would:

1. Ensure the song exists in the Songs table.
2. Ensure the next sequenced song is in ShowSonggref for the same show.

So only songs sequenced in the same show which are 1 after the next would be returned. but only the 1st in the pairing as the 2nd song Doens't have a subsequent song; however both songs are available since you have ref and ref2 to work with.

.

```
--SELECT sh.ID, s.Name, ref.SongOrder FROM Songs s 

SELECT sh.ID FROM Songs s
INNER JOIN ShowSongRef ref 
  ON ref.SongID = s.ID 
INNER JOIN ShowSongRef ref2 
  ON ref2.SongID = s.SongID  - ok we need to make sure the song is fk to songs
 and Ref2.SongOrder = Ref.SongOrder+1 --this is the trick (assumes song order is numeric)
 and ref.ShowID = ref2.ShowID -- we only want to consider songs in the same show
INNER JOIN Shows sh 
  ON sh.ID = ref.ShowID 
WHERE ref.SongID IN ('654', '321')
```

--ORDER BY sh.ID,  ref.SongOrder

Comment: I updated my question with some temp tables to test. Your suggestion seems like it should work but it's not.